# Putting footer at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am currently making an app. However, my footer is directly below the button. I would like my footer to be at the bottom of the app instead. I will attach a link to the picture of how it is looking like right now.

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
        <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
            <h1><b>Converter App</b></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="app">
            <a href="converter.html" class="ui-btn">Converter</a>
        </div>


        <footer data-role="footer">
            <h4>Copyright 2017</h4>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have added the CSS below as requested.

```
.ui-header-fixed,
.ui-footer-fixed {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMSRD.jpg

Comment: Could you let us know what CSS/JS did you use and what you tried to achieve this ?

Comment: @3Dos Hello !! I have added in the css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add css class or id

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

In html

```
<div id="footer">
    <h4>Copyright 2017</h4>
</div>
```

Explicity fix your footer container at the bottom of your page

https://jsfiddle.net/5qj7eggm/

Comment: Hello !! Unfortunately, the footer is still directly below the button.

Comment: Just as an aside (may not actually be a problem), but this will result in your footer always being visible at the bottom due to it's fixed position https://jsfiddle.net/5qj7eggm/1/, and so will always be visible regardless of the height of page content. May not be an issue depending on the app is going to end up looking like.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to first specify a minimum height of the app container like `body, #main-page { min-height: 100vh; }`

then stick the footer in the bottom

```css
body, #mainpage {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-header-fixed,
.ui-footer-fixed {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.ui-footer-fixed {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
  <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
    <h1><b>Converter App</b></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="app">
    <a href="converter.html" class="ui-btn">Converter</a>
  </div>


  <footer data-role="footer" class="ui-footer-fixed">
    <h4>Copyright 2017</h4>
  </footer>
</div>
```

You may also want to slightly modify the html structure in order to make your footer always visible.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

you need to add

```
#mainpage{
height:100vh;}
```

```css
.ui-header-fixed,
.ui-footer-fixed {
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#mainpage{
height:100vh;}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
        <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
            <h1><b>Converter App</b></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="app">
            <a href="converter.html" class="ui-btn">Converter</a>
        </div>


        <footer data-role="footer">
            <h4>Copyright 2017</h4>
        </footer>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```